# mysql loop en procedure

Tags: mysql, cursor

Por favor pido su amable ayuda para ayudarme a encontrar el problema. Estoy intentando en mysql 8 recorrer en un loop  un cursor. Sin embargo me arroja un error que no puedo detectar ya que no es claro el mensaje.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRC_SKU_STOCK_IMS_SELECT()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE VCOD_VENTA VARCHAR(64);
    DECLARE VLOCATION VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE flag INT DEFAULT 0;
    DEClARE cursor_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT COD_VENTA FROM SKU_STOCK_IMS WHERE IMS_STATUS = 0 LIMIT 1000;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cursor_1;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_1 into VCOD_VENTA;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        SELECT * from SKU_STOCK_IMS;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_1;

    SELECT COD_VENTA,LOCATION_CODE FROM SKU_STOCK_IMS WHERE IMS_STATUS = 1 LIMIT 1000;
END;
```

El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

> Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '' at line 17

Comment: Pues yo he probado tu código y funciona, no logro obtener el fallo que mencionas

Comment: En que version de mysql?

Comment: la 8 que mencionas en tu pregunta

Comment: Inclusive este repeat no puedo crearlo tal cual se muestra en la pagina oficial. Me muestra el mismo mensaje de error.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/repeat.html

Comment: no entiendo el punto de hacer un loop de esa manera existiendo el while

Comment: El while me genera el mismo mensaje de error. En realidad son dos maneras similares de hacerlo.

Comment: Si has hecho una copia desde la web seria bueno que quites las líneas en blanco o que te asegures que no hayan entrado caracteres especiales no visibles. Eso a veces me a sucedido y he tenido que sobrescribir  los espacios y quitar líneas en blanco. Segun el error esta en la línea 17 luego del close o línea en blanco. El error es cerca a '' nada.